# WCF Restful service bad performance

Tags: c#, wcf, performance, service

My wcf restful service manages to serve only 2 requests/sec!

detailed:

I've created a wcf restful service which exposes only one method via GET verb.
The method makes no logic, and returns immediately.

I've also created a test client in order to check the service throughput and performance, which makes requests by WebHttpRequest.

The service was able to process only 2 requests/sec!

I also made a request to the service through my browser, and the same result: 500ms for one request.

Then I changed the service binding to netTcpBinding and the service was able to process around 2000 requests/sec.

The service was running under a windows service, and hosted by WebServiceHost with WebHtppBinding.

good to mention that both client and the service was running in the same server.

Does it make any sense that wcf restful service has such poor performance?

Would Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: did you try hosting it in console app and consuming from another console app? also try using basichttpbinding for test purposes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it makes no sense and probably points to a problem with your testing. How was your REST test client written? Are you aware that, by default, .NET will only allow **two** open connections to any domain for a "regular" .NET process? It's increased to **ten** automatically for ASP.NET apps.

That information is documented here in [`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx). You can increase this programatically or [through config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1tkaca2y.aspx) by adding a higher limit for the domain you're trying to connect to. Config wise this would look something like this:

```
<system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
        <add address="www.myserver.com" maxconnection="20" />
    </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

You can open up connections for all domains using `address="*"` if that's your desire.

As for the delay you're seeing, it could be the result of other features that are on by default such as [`UseNagleAlgorithm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.usenaglealgorithm.aspx) or, if your POST'ing, [Expect100Continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.expect100continue.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Drew. But it still doesn't explain why a request from the browser takes 500msec.

Comment: what if you invoke the service programmatically? does not make any sense it would take 500ms.. something else is happening probably. possibly proxy delay

Comment: @Simon - well it certainly explains the the two connection limit, so that's half your question answered. As for the lag, I will bet this is the result of our friend the Nagle algorithm which is enabled by default. I will update my answer with details on disabling that.

Comment: @Drew - I've been setting the "DefaultConnectionLimit" to 100. There is better performance, but my service still is very slow compared when it is exposed via net.tcp. Furthermore, the Nagle algorithm is turned of in my client. I suspect the problem is somewhere in the service rather than the client. Could the slowness be related to http keep-alive?

Comment: Well, theoretically, keep-alive should be helping, not hurting. Perhaps it's time for you to post some code/config so we can figure this out. WebHttpBinding shouldn't be performing as poorly as you seem to be observing in a simple test case.

Comment: Well, I think I found the problem - The Nagle algorithm in the service side is enabled, which causes the 500msec delay, and thus reduces performance. Unfortunately I think there is no option to disable it as WebServiceHost doesn't expose this tuning. I disabled Nagling in the registry and the service was running fast!

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately there is no way to disable nagling on WCF server side AFAIK. You might want to go vote this connect issue up: http://connect.microsoft.com/wcf/feedback/details/644565/allow-the-ability-to-disable-the-nagle-algorithm-on-wcf-service